# unit test AngularJS $event with jasmin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, events

What would be the best way to test this directive function?

```
$scope.addToToList = function(event){
    var offset = $(event.target).offset();
    addToListService.showPopUp(offset.left, offset.top);
};
```

the directive's HTML template:

```
<div ng-click="addToToList($event)">
```

How do I test `$event`?

and how do I test that the `addToListService.showPopUp(x,y)` has been called? 
I would like to test offset to have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [spy](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) is probably what you need.

```
it("should call showPopUp with offset from event", function() {
  var
    offset = { left: 100, top: 200 },
    ev = {
      target: {
        offset: function () { return offset; }
      }
    };

  spyOn(addToListService, 'showPopUp');
  scope.addToToList(ev};
  expect(addToListService.showPopUp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(offset.left, offset.top);
});
```